# Keep only columns that meet a criterion

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large data frame whose values are either `TRUE`,`FALSE`, or `NA`. I want to keep only the columns that contains at least one `TRUE` value. How do achieve this?

Here's a minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(
   c1 = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),
   c2 = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,NA),
   c3 = c(FALSE,NA,TRUE,NA),
   c4 = c(FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA)
 )
> df
     c1    c2    c3    c4
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE  TRUE    NA FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA
4 FALSE    NA    NA    NA
```

I want to remove columns `c1` and `c4`, and keep only `c2` and `c3`. I know that `TRUE` values exist in my original larger data frame (using `table(df==TRUE)`), but I don't know which function(s) to use to identify their columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `select` with `any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   select(where(~ is.logical(.x) && any(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
  c2    c3
1 FALSE FALSE
2  TRUE    NA
3 FALSE  TRUE
4    NA    NA
```

---

Or in `base R` with `colSums` on the columns and check if the sum is greater than 1 (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
df[colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) > 0]
```

-output

```
   c2    c3
1 FALSE FALSE
2  TRUE    NA
3 FALSE  TRUE
4    NA    NA
```